# Changing the page of an embedded PDF

Tags: jquery, html, pdf, embed

I have a PDF that is embedded into a page using the embed tags.

```
<embed id="pdfdata" src="PDFFile.pdf#page=20&navpanes=0" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>
```

This works fine and the PDF opens to page 20 as required.

I later need to update this to a different page and have a function to do so:

```
function SelectPDFPage(page) {
    var location = "PDFFile.pdf#page=1&navpanes=0"
    $("#pdfdata").attr("src", location);
};
```

This updates the html but does not update the actual PDF. I have seen some other similar questions in relation to images; these suggest removing the embedded pdf and restoring it. I have tried this and the reload time is unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is waiting for the number of current page as a parameter, but it does not do anything with it. You have an unexpected semicolon after defining location variable. I think, you should try something like this:

```
function SelectPFGPage(page){
   var location = "PDFFile.pdf#page="+page+"&navpanes=0";
   jQuery("#pdfdata").attr("src", location);
}
```

I hope it works for you (I haven't tried it)